# RMVB encoder for Mac

Tags: macos, video, encoding, rmvb

Is there an RMVB encoder (RealVideo 9 & RealAudio 8 64kbps 44.1khz) for Mac?

I am currently running Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.4

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a commandline swiss army knife for video transcoding, check out http://www.ffmpeg.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here it is :

http://www.telestream.net/episode/overview.htm